# Unable to post a form when add custom attr on image tag IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor

Unable to post a form when add custom attr on image tag IE11. Is there any other way to accomplish this or i need to do in different manner?

```
contentCKEditor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'SimpleTemplate_HTML', {
'height': 400,
'removePlugins': 'autogrow',
'filebrowserImageWindowWidth' : '700',
'filebrowserImageWindowHeight' : '540',
'image_previewText': '',
'insertMode' : true,
});
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function( ev ) { 
        var dialogName = ev.data.name;
        var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

        dialogDefinition.removeContents('Link');
        if (dialogName == 'image') { 
            dialogDefinition.onOk = function(e) {
                var imageSrcUrl = e.sender.originalElement.$.src;
                var assetId = $('div[rel="ckeditor"]').attr('data-id');
                var style = "width:200px;";
                this.imageElement.setAttribute( 'data-assetid', assetId);
                this.imageElement.setAttribute( 'style', style);
                this.imageElement.setAttribute( 'src', imageSrcUrl );
                contentCKEditor.insertNode(this.imageElement);
           }
       } 
    });
```

Comment: What HTML is being generated? Is there an error? what research have you done so far?

Comment: <p><img data-assetid="6d39a9ec-8c4e-d297-786b-fecb9cc79e63" src="http://localhost/image/show/id/6d39a9ec.jpg" style="width: 200px;" /></p>

Comment: What does "Unable to post a form" mean? Do you get an error? Do you get a http 5xx code? Is the POST variables empty? Do you get a JavaScript error? Is the submit button gray and clicking does nothing? Does your body physically refuse to submit it? What is "this" in your code? Why not use a normal variable? Where is this.imageElement initialized and how?

Comment: "Unable to post a form" means submit button is not working after adding image from ckeditor dialog box. In this case, using ckeditor event "dialogDefinition" and add custom attribute in image tag, submit button of form is not working and no javascript error occur.

Comment: Does it work if you remove a single line from this code--the one where you set `data-assetid`?  I suspect the problem isn't with that line.  Also, does it work in other browsers?

Comment: After removing this line, it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that your form misses:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

When `enctype` is missing the `$_FILES` variable is not created

My form looks like this: (not using an custom filebrowser)

```
<form action="require/fileup.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="imageForm">
 <center>
  <input name="file_up" type="file" class="file_up">
 </center>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

In one of your comments you wrote

```
<p><img data-assetid="6d39a9ec-8c4e-d297-786b-fecb9cc79e63" src="localhost/image/show/id/6d39a9ec.jpg"; style="width: 200px;" /></p>
```

There is a semicolon AFTER src="" which should not be there. Could that be the problem or was this a typo?